# DELETE C# SqlCommand: Subquery returned more than 1 value

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server-2016, sqlcommand

I have an error doing either a `DELETE` or `INSERT` using a C# `SqlCommand`; database is SQL server.

The SQL statement is

```
DELETE FROM [table_name] 
WHERE id = 'some_id';
```

which is pretty simple.

`id` is a column name with datatype `varchar(15)` that can be NULL; `some_id` has 15 characters.

First, to verify that only 1 row with that `ID` exists, this `SELECT` query was made that returns no errors

```
SELECT * 
FROM [table_name] 
WHERE id = 'some_id';
```

returns 1 row

The error on the `DELETE` is

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.
>
> at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()

This error can happen when more than 1 row satisfy the criteria of the query; clearly not the case here

What is puzzling is that doing the same `DELETE` query using the C ODBC API there is no error; so it seems the problem is in the C# code

C# code that calls `DELETE`:

```
public int execute(string sql)
{
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(conn_str);

    try
    {
        conn.Open();

        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sql, conn);
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        conn.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
        return -1;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

C# code that calls `SELECT`:

```
public List<List<string>> select(string sql)
{
    Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
    sw.Start();

    List<List<string>> rows = null;
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(conn_str);

    try
    {
        conn.Open();

        SqlDataReader reader = null;
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sql, conn);
        reader = command.ExecuteReader();

        int nbr_cols = reader.FieldCount;
        int nbr_rows = 0;

        rows = new List<List<string>>();

        while (reader.Read())
        {
            nbr_rows++;
            List<string> col = new List<string>();

            for (int idx_col = 0; idx_col < nbr_cols; idx_col++)
            {
                 string str = reader[idx_col].ToString();
                 col.Add(str);
            }

            rows.Add(col);
        }

        reader.Close();
        conn.Close();

        sw.Stop();

        Console.WriteLine("Time to get {0} rows: {1} msec", nbr_rows, sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
    }

    return rows;
}
```

C++ DELETE code with no error

```
std::string sql = "DELETE FROM [some_table] WHERE ID='some_id';";
  if (query.exec_direct(sql) < 0)
  {
    std::cout << sql;
  }
```

where the function `exec_direct` is here

https://github.com/pedro-vicente/lib_odbc/blob/master/odbc.cc

thanks

EDIT

adding link to DELETE documentation

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/delete-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: You can't use `select *...` in your subquery. You need to `select Column_Name...`

Comment: @OrthoHomeDefense. SELECT allows for *. check the docs https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_select.asp

Comment: The error is `Subquery returned more than 1 value.` None of the queries you have shown have a subquery. Show us the query that you are getting this error from.

Comment: the SQL that I send to the C# function above named execute(string sql) is just this: "DELETE FROM [table_name] WHERE id='some_id';" yes, there is no sub query that's why I said that it makes no sense :-)

Comment: Unrelated tips: SqlConnection SqlCommand and SqlDataReader are all IDisposable so each should be in a `using` block. Once you've done that, you don't need to worry about closing the connection as it will be done by the implicit Dispose as it exits the block (even if there is an exception).

Comment: @Richardissimo. thanks, yes I know that. I just like to do an explicit "Close()" :-)

Comment: To find error you can use SQL Profiler to check queries sent to SQL Server engine.

Comment: You can do the Close as well if you like, but without a `using` block your code can leak resources. *"yes I know that"* is just irritating. If you know it, why aren't you doing it?

Comment: Is there by any chance a `AFTER DELETE` trigger on that table??

Comment: @Hamed, thanks, I'll try that, never used it before

Comment: @marc_s . ah, yes indeed there is a AFTER DELETE trigger. thanks, I''l check that ! :-)

Comment: And does that after delete trigger per chance contain a subquery somewhere? If so, I'm pretty sure that's your culprit  - not your code shown in your question

Comment: If this is caused by a trigger, how does the C++ code work?

Comment: @richardissimo the c++ code connects to a different database that doesn't have an after delete trigger..

Comment: Likely you are right, but I can't tell if you're kidding or if that is based on information in the question/comments, or the OPs odbc library that I've missed (e.g. line 540 it lists *all* databases by returning ones with `database_id>6`)

Comment: @Richardissimo. That is a good question ("how does the C++ code work?"). And to clarify it IS exactly the same database, of course.

Comment: @Richardissimo. Also thanks for looking at the ODBC library. That line 540 where it lists all databases it's just a function that is not called here (don't recall why the database_id>6, maybe to avoid "system tables"). If you look at the header file, the functions used are just "connect()" and the above code "exec_direct(sql)"

Comment: Also, I tried that C# code above in a "copy-cat" database (a database made up just getting the table and dummy data from the original database) and it worked fine.

Comment: so that leaves the AFTER DELETE trigger to look at...